# What's wrong with finding the maximum refraction angle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, visible-light, refraction

I am wrong with this derivation of $1 = \mu^2$ for arbitrary $\mu$ obviously, but I can't find what's wrong.

$\delta := \theta_{1} - \theta_{2} $ where $\frac{\sin \theta_{1}}{\sin \theta_{2}} = \mu_{12}$. 
So, 
$$
\frac{\sin \theta_{1}}{\sin \theta_{2}} = \mu_{12} \Rightarrow \theta_{1} = \arcsin \big(  {\mu \sin \ \theta_{2}} \big) .
$$ 
Putting in the definition 
$$
\delta \big(\theta_2 \big) := \arcsin \big(  {\mu \sin \ \theta_{2}} \big) -  \theta_{2} \Rightarrow \frac{d \delta \big( \theta_2 \big)}{d \theta_2 } = \frac{\mu \cos \big( \theta_2 \big)}{\sqrt {1 - \mu^2 \sin^2 \theta_2} } - 1   $$.
Finding the extrema, 
\begin{align}
&\frac{d\delta \big(\theta_2 \big)}{d \theta_2 } = 0 \\
&\Rightarrow \frac{\mu \cos \big( \theta_2 \big)}{\sqrt {1 - \mu^2 \sin^2 \theta_2} } = 1\\
&\Rightarrow \mu \cos \big( \theta_2 \big) = \sqrt {1 - \mu^2 \sin^2 \theta_2}\\
&  \Rightarrow \mu^2 \cos^2 \big( \theta_2 \big) = {1 - \mu^2 \sin^2 \theta_2}\\
&\Rightarrow 1 = \mu^2 (\cos^2 \big( \theta_2 \big)+\sin^2 \theta_2)
\end{align}

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Comment: It is not a homework question, I'm trying to do it by myself and solving my own question.

Comment: If you noticed the links I gave, you'd see that problems of this type *are* homework as we use the term here.

Comment: You just found that for matching refractive index, the deflection is an extreme (namely, a minimum). There is no "stationary" maximum - hence no other point where the derivative goes to zero. The greater the refractive index mismatch, the greater the deflection.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so when you have done that dδ(theta2)/dθ2=0 you are finding out the maxima i.e you'll get the value of "theta2" so as to obtain the maximum value of refraction angle whatsoever. Putting this value of theta 2 in  δ(θ2):=arcsin(μsin θ2)−θ2 will give you the maximum refraction angle indeed.

And when you are talking about the maximum refraction angle. The angle must be lesser (i am not sure its equal too) than the critical angle otherwise there would be Total internal reflection.

Comment: Either add it as a comment or delete it. I am too stupid to decipher your answer.